# Complex String Position

Tags: php, string

Given this string:

> Project ID|Project|Account Name|Severity|Status>|<406115|United
>   Equipment - Cabling fix|United Equipment Pty Ltd - Kewdale
>   (HO)|Installation|Wait For Response (customer)

I want to get the position of **Severity** and I'm expecting 3 or 4 as the output with **Pipe |** as separator. With 3 or 4, i can locate the value in the next part of the string after **>|<** so i'll be getting the fourth value after >|< which is **Installation**

I'll appreciate any help. Thank You!

Comment: Sounds like you need to discover [serialization](http://us1.php.net/serialize). Also, what you tried so far?

Comment: Try using `explode($str, '|')` first and then `array_search()`.

Comment: This can be treated as a `*.csv` file. If you replace `>|<` with `\n` and after that replace `|` with `,`. you can read this with `str_getcsv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 2 arrays

```
$str = "Project ID|Project|Account Name|Severity|Status>|<406115|United Equipment - Cabling fix|United Equipment Pty Ltd - Kewdale (HO)|Installation|Wait For Response (customer)";
$arrays = explode('>|<',$str );
$first = explode('|', $arrays[0]);
$severity_position = array_search('Severity', $first);
$second = explode('|', $arrays[1]);
```

Now `$second[3]` is installation value and `$severity_position` is your Severity index.

$first is exploded array before >|< and $second is exploded array after.

Comment: I've modified your code. I got the value in the second part by using $second[$severity_position].

Answer (score 0):

you can [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) the string with pipe and then use [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) to get the position

```
$str = "Project ID|Project|Account Name|Severity|Status>|<406115|United Equipment - Cabling fix|United Equipment Pty Ltd - Kewdale (HO)|Installation|Wait For Response (customer)"

$Severity_position = array_search('Severity', explode('|', $str));


$arr = explode('>|<', $str);
$installation_position = array_search('Installation',  explode('|', $arr[1]) );
```

Comment: This is awesome, how do I get Installation then?

Comment: try this
$arr = explode('>|<', $str); check updated answer

Comment: $arr[1] might be having different value on the 4th index. I think it's not a flawless idea to use 'Installation' in search